# Preventing desktop jump when window is open on another desktop?

Tags: macos, terminal, dock, mission-control

I have setup 2 Desktops in Mavericks (Mission Control).

- On "Desktop 2" there are some programs that need to run, but which I use rarely, for example a Terminal with some server tasks.
- Then on "Desktop 1" I want to run more Terminal instances, but when I click the icon in the dock, it jumps to the Terminal instance on the second desktop.

I tried disabling this setting, but then clicking the app icon does nothing (second click jumps to desktop 2):

- System Preferences > Mission Control > When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application

Any ideas or tools to solve this problem? Basically I want Mavericks to treat every Desktop separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems](http://mactips.dwhoard.com/mactips/other-applications/spaces-auto-switching) that what you are doing does not work the first time, but after **2** tries, it does. So do this to the 'When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application':

1. Turn it OFF in System Preferences → Mission Control
2. Turn it ON
3. Turn it OFF again.

You could also try typing this in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -boolean NO`

...but that is said to only work in OSX Leopard on the website above but 'jgl777' over [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4995042?tstart=0) said that it worked on his 10.8.3 Mountain Lion, so it's possible it could work on Mavericks. I would advise backing up if you do this, but you should be doing that even if you don't want to use this method!

Another option is to Ctrl + Click the application's icon in the dock and then click open in new window, this will open it in the current Desktop and a new window of the app.

Comment: With the setting disabled it only activates Terminal, but doesn't open a new window. Thanks for the tip with Ctrl-Click!

Answer (score 2):

At least on El Capitan, it is (apparently) necessary to restart the Dock after setting the value of `workspaces-auto-swoosh`

On the command line:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -boolean NO
killall Dock
```